# How to prepend 0 to a list of integers in Lisp

Tags: format, lisp, common-lisp

I have a list of integers **(3 11 7 26 5)**

I wrote a function to prepend 0 to 1-digit numbers:

```
(defun beautify (list)
  (mapcar #'0-add list))

(defun 0-add (1digit)
  (format nil "~2,'0d" 1digit))
```

it outputs **("03" "11" "07" "26" "05")**

However, I'd like to have **(03 11 07 26 05)**

How can I arrange it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
CL-USER 10 > (format t "(~{~a~^ ~})" '("03" "11" "07" "26" "05"))
(03 11 07 26 05)

CL-USER 11 > (format t "(~{~2,'0d~^ ~})" '(3 11 7 26 5))
(03 11 07 26 05)
```